# programacao java e conexao com banco de dados

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, conexão

Tenho um problema que esta me infernizando. É o seguinte:

Eu tenho um **banco de dados** e tenho o meu programa em **java** tudo conectado, ja criei o **jar** **file** e tudo.

Mas o problema é que o programa só corre na maquina perfeitamente na maquina em que o banco de dados esta instalado, eu gostaria de saber como garantir que a aplicação continuara a guardar dados sem no entanto ter o **banco de dados** instalado.

Basicamente eu preciso de saber de algum jeito como carregar o **banco de dados** junto com a minha aplicação.
package bie.trabalho.utilitarios;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ConnexaoOracle {

```
private String NomeDoUsuario;
private String Senha;
private String Caminho;

private final String host = "localhost";
private final String servico = "xe";
private final String PortaDeEntrada = "1521";


public Connection Connexao;

public ConnexaoOracle(String nome, String Senha) {

    setNomeDoUsuario(nome);;
    setSenha(Senha);
    setCaminho();

}

public void setNomeDoUsuario(String Nome){
    this.NomeDoUsuario =Nome;
}
public void setSenha(String senha){
    this.Senha = senha; 
}
private void setCaminho() {
    Caminho = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+host + ":" + PortaDeEntrada + ":" + servico; 

}

public String getSenha()
{
    return this.Senha;
}

public String getNomeDoUsuario() {
    return NomeDoUsuario;
}
public String getCaminho() {
    return Caminho;
}



public boolean Connectar()
{
    boolean vereficadorDeConexao = false;
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
        Connexao = DriverManager.getConnection(getCaminho(), getNomeDoUsuario(), getSenha());
        vereficadorDeConexao = true;

    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
            | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {

        vereficadorDeConexao = false;
    } 
    return vereficadorDeConexao;
}

public ResultSet ExecutarComandoSql(String Comando)
{
    ResultSet Resultados = null ;
    try {
        Statement Comandosql = Connexao.createStatement();
        Resultados = Comandosql.executeQuery(Comando.toUpperCase());


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return Resultados;  
}

public void commit()
{

    String Comando = "commit";
    ExecutarComandoSql(Comando );

} 

public void rollback()
{
    String Comando = "rollback";
    ExecutarComandoSql(Comando );

}
public boolean Disconnectar()
{
    boolean vereficadorDeDesconexao = false;
    try {
        Connexao.commit();
        Connexao.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {

    }

    vereficadorDeDesconexao = true;
    return vereficadorDeDesconexao;
}
```

}

Comment: Está usando qual banco de dados? É uma aplicação desktop usando swing? Adicione mais detalhes na pergunta.

Comment: Coloca o código ou arquivo de configuração do banco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua necessidade é de um [Embedded Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database), é um banco integrado a aplicação e que também roda junto a aplicação.

> Como pode ver no wikipedia, existe diversas opções, a diferença é como
>   será configurado os modos de armazenamento, em disco, em memória ou
>   uma combinação de ambos, certifique-se disso para não acabar perdendo
>   dados.

Geralmente em memória é usado em ambiente de desenvolvimento por ser mais rápido e mais simples de testar, pois os dados são apagados, cada vez que a aplicação é fechada.

Mas normalmente o modo de armazenamento em disco é o que acontece em banco de dados instalados separadamente.

***Segue algumas opções***

- http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html
- https://www.sqlite.org/
- https://github.com/vorburger/MariaDB4j
- https://db.apache.org/derby/
- http://hsqldb.org/

Comment: obrigado é disso mesmo que eu estou falando.